# Planning a trip to Venezuela — What are potential dangers and can't-miss locations?

Tags: travel, locations

I'm planning a trip to Venezuela in August and wanted some insight from photographers who have traveled through there recently.  Does anyone have any experiences they can share with me in regards to safety, dangers, security of photography equipment, and locations worth venturing to?  Any tips and information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

For the dangers, i would recommend the [Venezuela Travel Reports offered by the government of Canada](http://www.voyage.gc.ca/countries_pays/report_rapport-eng.asp?id=313000).

They are normally up-to-date and contains lots of important information about the precaution to take in this country.  The Venezuela report also contains a regional warning.

There are some Canadian specific info, but most of it is general for anybody in the world.

Also:

- Try not exposing too much your photographic equipment, bring the minimum of equipment (ideal would be a small camera you can carry in a pocket or in a small bag: small DSLR with compact lens, high end compact or APS-C compact (aka mirrorless)
- Avoid traveling the night for safety reasons
- You will be traveling during the rainy period (May through November), so bring the necessary to protect your equipment from the rain

Finally, read and bring 1 or 2 Venezuela travel guides (For example: lonely planet).  They list and recommend hotels and restaurants, and they will help you finding the spots to visit and hopefully take good pictures.

Take care!

Comment: Thanks decastlejau!  I will definitely investigate the Travel Report you suggested.  I'm sure this resource will prove informative.  Cheers!

Comment: Happy to share. In my last trip to Guatemala, I found some very valuable information in the Guatemala report.  We avoided a city in particular for our safety, and followed a few recommendations.

Comment: I've looked at the Travel Reports, very valuable information.  Particularly the information about safety threats.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Always carry photography gear in carry-on luggage, no one treats your luggage like you do!

Comment: Very true Chris.  I never check-in my equipment baggage.

Comment: that's good advise worldwide :) The way luggage gets literally thrown around, it's a miracle not more of it ends up destroyed (I've seen myself luggage trucks on ramps dropping suitcases, then backing up over them so the driver doesn't have to walk around the vehicle to pick them up again for example).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've heard of [Isla Margarita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isla_Margarita). Also, I wouldn't miss the [Andean region](http://www.google.com/images?q=andes+venezuela).

Answer (score 0):

Just two words: Travel insurance.